# How do I throttle the amount of data sent to Stomp queue (handling websockets) so that I can guarantee that I don't overflow the buffer?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp, throttling

I have two Java processes and I am connecting them using a websocket in spring boot. One process acts as the client and connects like this:

```
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>(1);
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
    WebSocketClient client = new SockJsClient(transports);

    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

    StompSessionHandler firstSessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler("Philip");
    stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080/chat", firstSessionHandler);
```

The session handler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter and provides these methods (I am subscribing by username so each client can receive its own messages):

```
@Override
public void afterConnected(
        StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
    session.subscribe("/user/" + userName + "/reply", this);
    session.send("/app/chat", getSampleMessage());
}

@Override
public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
    Message msg = (Message) payload;
    // etc.....
}
```

On the server side I have a Controller exposed and I am writing data by calling the endpoint from a worker thread.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@MessageMapping("/chat")
public void send(
        Message message)
        throws Exception {

    template.convertAndSendToUser(message.getFrom(),
                             "/reply",
                                        message);
}
```

In the websocket config I am overriding the method to set the limits:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setMessageSizeLimit(500 * 1024);
    registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024);
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(20000);
}
```

My question is this, if the load on the server gets high enough and I overrun the limit, the websocket fails catastrophically, and I want to avoid this. What I would like to do is for the controller to have the ability to ask the message broker "will this message fit in the buffer?", so that I can throttle to stay under the limit. I searched the API documentation but I don't see any way of doing that. Are there any other obvious solutions that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a solution, so if anyone is interested, here it is.

On the server side configuration of the websockets I installed an Interceptor on the Outbound Channel (this is part of the API), which is called after each send from the embedded broker.

So I know how much is coming in, which I keep track of in my Controller class and I know how much is going out through the Interceptor that I installed, and this allows me to always stay under the limit.

The controller, before accepting any new messages to be queued up for the broker first determines if enough room is available and if not queues up the message in external storage until such time as room becomes available.

Comment: Can you please post the sample code on how you achieved this?